# mysql error: Can't create a new thread (errno 11)

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I have a db server running MySQL Server, and 5 slaves. I always get the error:

```
mysql error: Can't create a new thread (errno 11); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug
```

Though I set ulimited

```
root@master:~# ulimit -a
core file size (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority (-e) 0
file size (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals (-i) 2062915
max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files (-n) 1000000
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority (-r) 0
stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes (-u) 1000000
virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks (-x) unlimited


root@master:~# cat /proc/`pidof mysqld`/limits | egrep "(processes|files)"
Max processes 1000000 1000000 processes
Max open files 1000000 1000000 files
```

Every request to the db server is around 30k.

Answer (score 0):

can you post the  [mysqld] section from your my.cnf. It resides in /etc/mysql if you installed from ubuntu packages or in /etc with the community install from mysql.com. If you do not have such a file this could already be the problem, because you are running an comile time defaults.

Also please issue a

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%';

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%Thread%';

and post the output.